# Creating dependent dropdowns in a grid using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm attempting to create a data-bound table with two dropdown columns.  However, the options available in the right dropdown are dependent on what's selected in the left dropdown.  For example, imagine `DropdownA` has a list of states, and `DropdownB` has a list of cities in that state.  My template looks like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: MeasurementInfoPlans -->
<tr>
   <td><select id="DropdownA" data-bind="options: $root.AllStates, optionsValue: 'State', optionsText: 'Name', value: StateId"></select></td>
   <td><select id="DropdownB" data-bind="options: $root.AllCities, optionsValue: 'City', optionsText: 'Name', value: CityId"></select></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Right now, `DropdownB` shows every item in `$root.AllCities`.  However, I want it to *only* show cities that have a `State` property of whatever value is selected in `DropdownA`.

I've found various examples online on how to define dependent dropdowns using a computed observable, however these examples assume you only have a single source dropdown (such as State).  In my case, I need to create an arbitrary number of dropdown *pairs* within the grid.  Does anyone have an example of how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put the cities on the `state` object, and then track them as a `computed` on the row item, since it will have an obserable for the state selection. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/jP8SY/)

html:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.states,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: state"></select>
<select data-bind="options: cities, value: city"></select>
```

js:

```
    self.state = ko.observable("");
    self.city = ko.observable("");
    self.cities = ko.computed(function(){
        if(self.state() == "" || self.state().cities == undefined)
            return [];
        return self.state().cities;
    });
```

Comment: Ooh this looks promising!  However, I'll have to wait until tomorrow when I'm back in the office to try it out.  `+1` for now!

Answer (score 1):

Two solution comes into my mind:

- subscribe to the observableArray of `DropdownA` in the viewmodel and replace the range of the cities in the observableArray of `DropdownB`  whenever it changes
- use an observable datacontext: use an observable as the options source so you can change it when you need too. Subscribe to `DropdownA` as in the first one and replace the entire city collection whenever it changes

I would choose the second one, because that's more clean.

[here is a jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/yBwe6/) I made for you.

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: dropdownA, value: dropdownAValue">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: dropdownB">
</select>
```

Js:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var _this = this,
        dataSource1,
        dataSource2;

    dataSource1 = ["Hello"];
    dataSource2 = ["World"];

    _this.dropdownA = ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]);
    _this.dropdownB = ko.observable(dataSource1);
    _this.dropdownAValue = ko.observable();

    _this.dropdownAValue.subscribe(function() {
        if (_this.dropdownAValue() == "A") {
            _this.dropdownB(dataSource1);   
        } else {
            _this.dropdownB(dataSource2);   
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Then it's easy to use this concept in multiple rows: http://jsfiddle.net/jGRQH/

Html:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
       <td>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.dropdownA, value: dropdownAValue">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: dropdownB">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
var rowViewModel = function(dataSource1, dataSource2) {
    var _this = this;

    _this.dropdownB = ko.observable(dataSource1);
    _this.dropdownAValue = ko.observable();

    _this.dropdownAValue.subscribe(function() {
        if (_this.dropdownAValue() == "A") {
            _this.dropdownB(dataSource1);   
        } else {
            _this.dropdownB(dataSource2);   
        }
    });
};

var mainViewModel = function() {
    var _this = this,
        dataSource1,
        dataSource2,
        addRow;

    dataSource1 = ["Hello"];
    dataSource2 = ["World"];

    addRow = function () {
        _this.rows().push(new rowViewModel(dataSource1, dataSource2));
    };

    _this.rows = ko.observableArray();

    _this.dropdownA = ko.observableArray(["A", "B"]);

    addRow();
    addRow();
    addRow();
};

ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel());
```

Comment: You beat me while I was making the fiddle =P

Comment: I was making a fiddle too :)

Comment: From what I can tell, this won't work because every row bound to DropdownB would also change.

Comment: yes, this is an only an example of dependent dropdowns, not the complete grid